# Is it possible to set Azure AD directory role via group membership?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Users in Azure AD can have a Directory role of "User", "Global administrator", or "Limited administrator."

Is it possible to grant these roles via group membership?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now , you cannot assign Directory roles to Azure AD Group.

You can only assign directory to users. See more details about Assigning administrator roles in Azure Active Directory in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles-azure-portal).

Also, you may want to use [**RBAC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is) to control access to resouces for dictory users and groups. With RBAC, you can assign access to groups and users. The below screenshot shows how to assign access to one Azure AD Group:

[image]

See more details about how to assign access to one group in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-access-powershell#grant-access).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wayne - is it still the case that you cannot assign Directory Roles to Azure AD Groups?  I cannot do it in my portal, but wasn't sure what the roadmap looked like for this feature.

Comment: Hi,@Cleaner. Yeah, this is still the case. You cannot  assign Directory Role to Groups for now.

Answer (score 0):

Groups are meant for resource access management. We can’t do operations related to user permissions with the help of groups.